# Execution failed for task ':vision-camera-code-scanner:checkDebugAndroidTestAarMetadata'

Tags: android, react-native, testing, build, detox

So I have been at this for a while now, I recently tried to add Detox tests to android in my react native projects.

I followed the official Detox tutorial and this one
https://varunon9.medium.com/e2e-testing-of-react-native-app-android-using-detox-a-step-by-step-guide-bfb520c1a9ac But when I'm trying to build the project `detox build -c android.emu.debug` I keep getting this exception:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> Execution failed for task
> ':vision-camera-code-scanner:checkDebugAndroidTestAarMetadata'. A
> failure occurred while executing
> com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction The
> minCompileSdk (31) specified in a dependency's AAR metadata
> (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties) is greater
> than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30). Dependency:
> androidx.camera:camera-extensions:1.1.0-beta02. AAR metadata file:
> ./directory-location/aar-metadata.properties.

I kept looking online and all I found was this 2 pages

https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/issues/934

https://groups.google.com/a/android.com/g/camerax-developers/c/Gc4yAR2l9I0

But it didn't help because my compileSdkVersion is already 31 as well as my targetSdkVersion...

I will really appreciate it if you help me, tnx.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem, in your `android/build.gradle` add:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        ...
        VisionCameraCodeScanner_targetSdkVersion = 31
        VisionCameraCodeScanner_compileSdkVersion = 31
    }
    ...
}
```

this simply sets `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` version to 31 which fixed the problem for me. (make sure to clean your build folder after)